# Wordpress: Trying to echo taxonomy slugs of individual downloads, but limit them to the $atts[category] selected from shortcode from post

Tags: php, wordpress, echo, taxonomy, shortcode

*Note: I'm a reasonable newcomer to .PHP, starting with this project. I understand the concept of it, but I'm not yet skilled enough to figure out what functions I need to use for something a bit complex, such as the following:*

**Backstory:**

I am presently working on a Wordpress site with a series of downloads pulled by shortcode; the code itself is almost entirely based on the Easy Digital Downloads plugin, with a bit of code added so that the downloads can be filtered (AJAX style) by category.

This is what the front end user should see:

http://kidzneurosciencecenter.com/download-problem-example-code/

The downloads on this page are generated by the following shortcode:

```
[downloads category="bs-safetyguides"]
```

"bs-safetyguides" is among 10 or so other category slugs associated with various downloads.

The problem isn't with the filter that brings up the downloads. That has been unchanged from Easy Digital Downloads and works well.

The problem is my modification (what else?), namely the code that writes the "All Files / Supplemental Content / Safe Cycling Guides" category filter on top of the downloads themselves. This is generated with a code that checks through the list of categories associated with the downloads and makes active only the items that have their category slug listed directly in their individual HTML entries.

For instance, if a download has the following code: `<div class= bs-safetyguides fusion-portfolio-post...`, the presence of `bs-safetyguides` will activate the filter for that slug, thus displaying the category "Safe Cycling Guides" as a selection for front end users.

**Here is my problem:**

So far, I know how to do one of two things.

**A.** I can write the specific category slugs associated with a single download, as follows:

```
<?php $individualdlcats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'download_category'); foreach ($individualdlcats as $taxindex => $taxitem) { echo $taxitem->slug,' ';};?>
```

Problem is, this writes ALL the categories associated with a download item. Case in point, the "NHTSA:Fitting a Helmet" download on the test page carries two shortcodes: `bs-safetyguides` and `bs-supplemental-content`. This code will echo both slugs into the HTML, e.g.:

```
<div class= bs-safetyguides bs-supplemental-content fusion-portfolio-post...
```

Thus resulting in both categories showing up in the front end category selection, even if I requested - by shortcode - only the items categorized by the `bs-safetyguides` slug.

**B.** I can echo the category slugs that I've requested by shortcode on a page:

```
$categories = explode( ',', $atts['category'] );
foreach( $categories as $category ) {
echo $category;
};
```

Of course, this only writes the category slug from the shortcode that I requested on a page; thus, if my shortcode is `[downloads category="bs-safetyguides"]`, all the downloads that come up get `bs-safetyguides` echoed in their HTML, whether that download is associated with it or not.

**This is what I need to do, somehow:**

I need to echo the unique category slugs of each individual download, minus any category slugs that are not specifically requested in the slug argument(s) called in the shortcode.

I'll be darned if I know how to do that with my knowledge of .PHP. Perhaps its staring me in the face and I haven't realized it - and it probably has, as the individual downloads need to be written properly, somehow.

Thank you so much!

**EDIT:**

Well, I've been pulling my hair out on this, and I think I've found something usable - but my lack of PHP knowledge is working against me. I'm trying to use `array_intersect` to filter the categories, but I can't seem to pass the array.

This is what I have now, and I've also experimented without the `foreach` lines:

```
$individualdlcats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'download_category'); 
foreach ($individualdlcats as $individualdlcats1 ) ;

$shortcodecatslugs = explode( ',', $atts['category'] );
foreach( $shortcodecatslugs as $shortcodecatslugs1 ) ;

$newArray = array_intersect( $individualdlcats1, $shortcodecatslugs1 );
foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value "; 
};
```

I'm almost certain my problem is related to the fact that the variables  `$individualdlcats` and `$shortcodecatslugs` (or `$individualdlcats1` and `$shortcodecatslugs1`, depending on what I call in `array_intersect`) are not actually pure arrays of the post slugs, but contain multiple strings within them.

Hence, I tried this:

```
$individualdlcats = get_the_terms($post->ID, 'download_category'); 
foreach ($individualdlcats as $taxitem) { 
$testarrayA = $taxitem->slug;
}

$shortcodecatslugs = explode( ',', $atts['category'] );
foreach( $shortcodecatslugs as $shortcodecatslugs1 ) {
$testarrayB = $shortcodecatslugs1->slug;
}

$newArray = array_intersect($testarrayA, $testarrayB);

foreach ($newArray as $key => $value) {
    echo "$value "; 
};
```

And that spits out blank too. Any ideas?